# Error in formula when comparing two separate formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the first and second formula to make sure the number I get is the same, which it is (32). The bottom formula however displays false and I have no clue why. (JA2 has a formula which outputs "32(22)"). Can anyone help me understand how they are not equal?

```
=LEFT(JA2,2)
=ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY())
=LEFT(JA2,2)=ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY())
```

Answer (score 1):

LEFT returns a string ISOWEEKNUM returns a number.  A string will not equal a number.  Turn the string to a number:

```
=--LEFT(JA2,2)=ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY())
```

The `--` or double unary is akin to `-1*-1*` which will change the string to a number if possible or return an error.  So you may want to use IFERROR to deal with that possibility:

```
=IFERROR(--LEFT(JA2,2),60)=ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY())
```

Now if the Left is a string that cannot be converted to a number the formula will return `60` and since there can only be a max of `53` weeks it will return `FALSE`